# Measuring data traffic flow over server/client socket in delphi?

Tags: delphi, sockets, pascal

i am making a program that sends data between a server program and its clients. They all use the server and client socket components found in Delphi! I have looked on the Internet and cannot find a way on how to measure how much data has been transferred through a socket!
Any help, especially some code (pascal/Delphi), would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you have a full example http://delphi.about.com/od/fullcodeprojects/l/aa112903a.htm

Comment: thank you for that link, but im looking for something more specific. I need to know how much data is traveling through a particular port or socket. That program just tells me all the data thats going through the pc! The code in there is also quite complex. I'm sure there is some simple one or two line code that should work for this problem!

Comment: Does anyone here know how to do this?

Comment: @Michael: Yes.  As I mentioned in my answer, you can monitor a specific port (service) and either do something with the data or just collect the statistics.

Answer (score 1):

If you use win/*nix API sockets (not a special libraries) you have to count returns from `recv` and `send` functions.

```
total_data = 0;
...
...
get_data = recv(...)
total_data = total_data + get_data
...
send_data = send(...)
total_data = total_data + send_data
```

Comment: yeah but isn't there a way to like get the size of the "socket, TCustomWinSocket" just before it is sent of or received. Like in the onRead or on onWrite event handlers! That should be a simple way of doing it!

Answer (score 1):

[Magenta Systems](http://www.magsys.co.uk/delphi/magmonsock.asp) has a free set of components that can monitor network traffic using either raw sockets or [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/).

Update:

From your comment to RBA's response: The Magenta components let you identify and differentiate between different IP addresses and services (ports).

Comment: Thanx, that might help! I've got a another idea! Since all my data is being transfered in plain text! How do you measure the kb size of a string of text?

Comment: You get details on the size of each packet, so you don't need to parse the contents of the packet if you don't want to.  You can even set a flag to ignore the data itself and just collect the statistics of bytes sent and received.  Check out the two example programs.

Answer (score 0):

I keep stats on all my TCP traffic to the byte. Every time I send data I update the stats and every time I receieve data I update the stats. This is accurate to one byte and requires only a few lines of code. And it does not rely on any particular TCP components. Why is doing it this way so hard?